# Подскажите с чего лучше начать учить java

Tags: java

Начал заниматься андроид разработкой, но из-за среднего уровня знаний java, есть с этим некоторые правила.
Подскажите источники для изучения java и android studio в частности, по мимо метонита.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Comment: Из книг Хорстманн, Шилдт. За Хорстманна знаю точно, что у него 2 тома: первый больше по core, особенно вторая часть книги интересная, а второй том по расширенным средствам программирования. Ресурсы в интернете, на подобие Metanit — это просто дополнение к основным знаниям (туда полезно заходить, когда не понятно, как используется какой-то класс и т.п.) и то, я сначала залез бы в официальную документацию JDK