# Подскажите что почитать/посмотреть про многонитевость Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Во время изучения Java дошёл до темы про многонитевость, но где это используется (да и вообще что это такое) нормальных примеров и описаний не встретил...

Понял только что многонитевость может работать с одноядерными процессорами используя быстрый переход между задачами, или с многоядерными используя сразу несколько ядер (но даже это каким-то образом Java решает на своё усмотрение)...

Есть ли нормальное описание в какой ни будь статье/книге/ролике на Youtube с адекватными примерами для новичков?

Comment: `многонитевость` это какой то новый сленг? Режет просто глаза такое написание.

Comment: [Java Concurrency in Practice. Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 ну это скорее не сленг, а перефразирование... Я понимаю что правильно называть данный процесс "Multithread", но всё скатываюсь в потребность мозга называть вещи простыми для него словами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое лучшее, что видел это книга Хорстманна. Первый том. Там раздел по многопоточности. Но нужно искать последнего издания, так как сейчас везде используются возможности java 8 (Lambda, Stream api) и хорошо бы сразу на таких примерах изучать.

Для разнообразия можно Шилдта почитать, но у него слишком затянуто как по мне.

Тут советуют  книгу java concurrency in practice, моё мнение, что она слишком сложная для новичка.

Опять же на ютубе лекции есть в свободном доступе, например автор Тагир Валеев.