# Взаимодействие с сайтом через java программу

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Я хочу написать java программу которая будет взаимодействовать с сайтом подобно пользователю, зашедшему на него, возможно ли такое сделать? Если можно, то опишите в общих чертах что для этого может понадобится кроме самой java программы(какие ещё языки потребуются).

Comment: "возможно ли такое сделать?" --- Да. " что для этого может понадобится" -- прочтите книги по Java. (популярное сейчас изготовление с помощью spring фреймворка)

Comment: вот книги https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/191482, включая про spring и hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совсем подобно юзеру из браузера и сайт с динамическим контентом (данные подгружаются и отрисовываются после загрузки основной страницы) - то используйте виртуальный браузер. Silenium, например.

Если же имеется в виду делать запросы к API сайта под видом залогиненного юзера - изучите как работает API сайта и шлите простые HTTP запросы, авторизованные через куки, заголовки, параметры запроса или как там в API имеется в виду.