# Как через метод convert создать конвертацию евро в доллары

Tags: java

Учусь на Java junior и у меня задачка с которой не могу справиться. Нужно создать метод convert, который должен конвертировать евро в доллары. В метод должен приходить один аргумент (кол-во евро). Метод должен возвращать кол во долларов.

Comment: Что вы хотите, чтобы вам ответили? Код написали или что? Что вам из всего не ясно и доставляет сложности?

Comment: Просто в моем курсе не было ничего про это, и у меня уже личный интерес, просто как выглядет сам код интересно, хочу просто что бы помогли с кодом, если кто знает. 
Private static Boolean convert(String str){
String res = str + str1; return res; у меня выдаёт ошибку компеляции. Не могу построить его так что бы работал, что бы смог конвертировать. Если можете написать просто код, то был бы очень признателен. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: думаю вам просто надо прочитать книгу для новичков и всё, тогда уже, после прочтения и прийти. если вдруг всё же не получится. а после прохождения курса по операторам if else конечно ещё ничему нельзя научиться

Comment: А просто написать код я так понимаю это слишком не подъёмная ноша ? Благодарю за ответ

Comment: А прочитать книгу для новичков где всё расписано и разжёвано,  я так понимаю, это тоже слишком не подъёмная ноша

Comment: Ну вы хоть напишите что за книга, я и понятия не имею о чем вы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/191482 тык

Comment: Примнрго благодарен

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Могу обьяснить код если нужно))

```
public double convert(double euro) {
    return euro * 1.14;
  }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду очень вам признателен

Comment: @АндрейЕвстафьев а что конкретно не понятно? тут ведь все банально

Comment: Нет нет, спасибо. Я уже разобрался. Ещё раз большое спасибо