# ООП парадигма, сокрытие данных. Зачем нужны protected и public?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, ооп

я изучаю ООП, и мне не понятна концепция сокрытия данных. По задумке: поля объекта должны изменяться только функциями внутри объекта, поэтому во всех крупных проектах в 100% случаев модификатор поля приватный чтобы свойства сущности можно было изменить только функциями сущности, в этом есть идея и логика. Тогда зачем нужен public и protected модификаторы?

Comment: Чтобы разрушить концепцию, так?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что такое "парадигма"?

Answer (score 2):

`public` - может быть полезен для внешних пакетов, которые будут использовать ваш `class`. так же если у вас нет какой то сложной логики связанных с установкой значения и его чтения, то вполне можно и `public` воспользоваться

`protected` - если вы хотите, чтобы изменять поле можно было только в дочерних классах, а не их экземплярах. С таким кейсом вы точно когда нибудь встретитесь

Answer (score 0):

> Тогда зачем нужен public и protected модификаторы?

Применений куча. Вам просто надо почитать побольше книги. Самое простое:

public - сделать dto, pojo. protected - для наследования

Так что вам надо продолжить изучение дальше

[Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/191482)

Answer (score 0):

public навскидку

1. для final констант
2. Для factory методов
3. для конструкторов. Не в одном же package живем
4. для интерфейсов
5. getter, setter
6. для утилитарных методов.

Answer (score 0):

> зачем нужен public и protected модификаторы?

public для переменных - плохо, а вот для констант вполне приемлемо.

---

protected используется в подклассах, а значит родительский класс является составной частью каждого подкласса и в некоторых случаях просто необходимо иметь доступ к родительским полям. Причём мы всё так же закрыты от внешнего кода, но имеем прямой доступ к унаследованным полям, что быстрее, чем геттер/сеттер.

---

Модификаторы доступа - это инструмент разработчика, где общая рекомендация: делать доступ как можно приватным. Начинай с private и по мере необходимости расширяй область видимости.