# Как научиться создавать программы на Java?

Tags: java

Как научиться создавать программы на Java?

Синтаксис я выучил.
Но вызывает сложность создание программ.
Пытаюсь делать по аналогии, компануя разные элементы. Для этого смотрю разные ролики на Youtube, где делают разные программы.
Но далеко не всегда все сочетается между собой. Куча ошибок и пр.

Думаю, может на основе проектов изучать?

Подскажите сервисы для изучения Java на основе создания проектов

Или с чего посоветуете начать?

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ

Comment: https://github.com/karan/Projects  ....  https://github.com/practical-tutorials/project-based-learning  и работа - вот где можно изучать на практике всё

Comment: *"Куча ошибок и пр."* - берете и разбираетесь с каждой ошибкой. *"смотрю разные ролики на Youtube, где делают разные программы"* - лучше так не делать

Comment: "с чего посоветуете начать?"  --- с прочтения книги https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/191482   чуть больше чем 20 страниц по базовому синтаксису

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На самом деле, если вы уже выучили синтаксис и базовые понятия, учиться можно на основе проектов на гитхабе. Найдите для начала небольшой проект, который вам понравится, и переписывайте код, начиная с входной точки. Важно понимать что делает каждая строчка, если что-то непонятно или будут вылезать ошибки - Гугл вам поможет. Если будете так делать, поймете как вообще пишутся программы, как стоит писать код, структуру проекта и т.д.

Answer (score -1):

Советую поискать мини курсы (можно на youtube) по фразе "Создание <игры/калькулятора/веб-приложения/клиент-сервера> на Java

Годный курс это когда все шаги плюс минус объясняются и вам все сразу понятно, либо вопросы решаются с одним/двумя последующими предметными запросами к поисковой системе.

В нашем деле главное практика, и хороший пример. Удачи в обучении!

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я опубликовал это как ответ, и убежден что это действительно ответ к данному вопросу. Если ваше субъективное мнение с этим расходится, это не значит что надо сразу минусовать ответ. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @noob_saibot я бы предложил именно автору решать о пользе ответа.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin уточню еще раз, на всякий случай. У человека конкретный вопрос - "что делать когда выучил синтаксис, но еще не научился писать программы?" и скидывать ему в этом случае Roadmap по изучению джавы (лонгрид непонятный для новичка), очень глупая затея, на мой взгляд. По существу, единственное что может заинтересовать человека - это практика программирования, а не теоретические догмы. Ибо как программист он будет писать, а не только читать. И вот выгореть пока только читаешь, но не пишешь, можно ой как легко.