# Чем void отличается от public void?

Tags: java, ооп, классы, void

Я видел, что люди используют просто void, а иногда public void. В какой ситуации нужно использовать *void*. И чем void отличается от public void.

Comment: void не имеет отношения к ООП. Это значит, что функция не возвращает значения

Comment: Так, а когда ставить public перед void. Или тут нет разницы?

Comment: public - модификатор доступа (видимости метода класса снаружи)

Comment: Это не правило программистов, так в любой сфере. Но лучше перед этим сформулировать у себя в голове как можно точнее сам вопрос и попытаться самому на него ответить

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 2):

`void` значит, что функция не возвращает значения. Это такой же тип, как `int`, `string` и пр. А вот `public` применяют потому, что по умолчанию,  модификатор доступа `private` (хотя не помню точно) и его кто-то опускает, а кто-то пишет.

А вот разница между `public` и `private` уже имеется

---

UPD. Статусы видимости при модификаторах доступа

```
Access Levels
Modifier        Class    Package    Subclass    World
-----------------------------------------------------
public           Y        Y          Y           Y
protected        Y        Y          Y           N
(Default)        Y        Y          N           N
private          Y        N          N           N
```

Т.е. если не указывать, то используется default

Comment: Все, вы мне помогли. Мучил голову над этим вопросом) Спасибо.