# Как вывести строку так, что-бы каждый символ выводился с новой строки?

Tags: java, строки, io

У меня есть строка:

```
String str = "Hello!";
```

Как сделать так что-бы каждый символ выводился с новой строки?

Пример:

Ввод:

```
Hello!
```

Вывод:

```
H

e

l

l

o

!
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Comment: Цикл? Генерация новой строки с разделителем `\n` между символами?

Comment: Да, что-то подобное.

Comment: Это я вам варианты подкидываю, т.к. на этом сайте правила обязывают помогать, а не решать за кого-либо :) Я вам покажу пример, но это для общего развития `System.out.println(str.chars().mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i)).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));`, т.к. в реальности лучше так не делать ;)

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Буду рыться)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть масса способов:

- Самый простой вывод символов строки в цикле с использованием `System.out.println`:

```java
for (char c : "Hello!".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

- Аналогично со Stream API:

```java
"Hello!".chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Вставить после каждого символа перевод строки при помощи `String::replaceAll`:

```java
System.out.println("Hello!".replaceAll("(.)", "$1\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //Создаем Scanner in
    String str = in.nextLine(); //Считываем (всю) строку

    String[] strSplit = str.split(""); //Разбиваем её на символы и записываем в массив.

    int i = 0;
    int lenght = str.length(); //Узнаем количество элементов 
                               //массива(количество символов строки).

    while(i < lenght) {
        System.out.println(strSplit[i]); //Выводим каждый элемент отдельно.  
        i++;
    }
```

Про Split можете почитать здесь: https://javarush.com/groups/posts/2907-metod-split-v-java-delim-stroku-na-chasti (Читать ОЧЕНЬ внимательно!)

Answer (score -1):

Просто после нужной буквы ставим \n и все. Например: “H\ne\nl\nl\no\n“