# программируем на java. 5-е издание от o'reilly, подойдет ли книга новичкам в сфере программирования?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, книги

Я новичок в сфере программирования, планирую начать изучение спринга по книге спринг бут по быстрому, но сейчас закрываю дыры в самом языке программирования java, поэтому взор попал на "программируем на java. 5-е издание" от o'reilly, но описание так и не понял, так вот пользователи которые проходили данную книгу, стоит ли ее читать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Изучил Java + Scala + Spring за пару месяцев, вообще не используя никаких книг. Просто устроился фронтэнд разработчиком в компанию где пишут на Java большие проекты. Спустя 5 лет пишу на Java как на родном, вообще без запинов и заглядываний в доку.

Comment: Вообще считаю, что учится на реальных боевых задачах, под присмотром тимлида - намного выгоднее 1000 книг. Учишься быстро, правильно а главное тому что реально нужно, а не устаревшую инфу которая тебе может даже некогда не пригодится.

Comment: На такой вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ.  Можете читать эту книгу, можете читать другие книги -- Шилдта / Эккеля / Гослинга, можете учить на курсах или по урокам в ютубе... [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/)

Comment: @Eugene X Читаю тебя и сразу вспоминается песня: "Фантазер, ты меня называла")))

Comment: @Atamiq за 8 месяцев, 7 вопросов 0 ответов? Да вы батенька эксперт!

Comment: @Eugene Задело? Ну, не обижайся) Взрослый мальчик уже. Спасибо за эксперта, приятно. Да здесь и экспертом не нужно быть, чтобы определить фантазера. Кстати, как тебе эта песня?

Comment: @Atamiq ничуть, мы преследуем разные цели, я помочь людям разобраться в их проблемах и ответить по существу, а так-же изучить что-то новое. Вы потролить местных жителей) Не знаю, я её не слышал) Видимо поэтому я так быстро и обучаюсь, что знаю где получать полезную информацию)

Comment: @Eugene Ну что вы. У меня и в мыслях не было троллить местных аборигенов. Признаю, есть слабость сказать человеку что он фантезер, каюсь. У меня к вам вопрос. Вы только Java+Scala+Spring освоили за 2 месяца или попутно еще несколько яп? Право, мне кажется вы просто скромничаете. С вашим талантом "фантазер" вы способны на большее, я вас в этом уверяю.