# Запрос пользователя

Tags: java

Возможно вопрос покажется глупым но что-то я совсем забыл как это делается...

```
package org.example;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите первое число: ");
        int number_1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Введите второе число: ");
        int number_2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number_1 * number_2);
}
```

}

Хочу чтобы он в итоге вывел именно так, например: 123 * 45 = (number_1 * number_2) т.е 5 535 но как мне написать то что я еще не знаю что он введет?

Comment: конкатенацию строк знаете? вот напишите это выражение через конкатенацию строк ........ если продвинуте, то через интерполяцию строк (https://javarush.com/groups/posts/4068-kofe-breyk-206-kak-preobrazovatjh-inputstream-v-stroku-na-java-5-sposobov-interpoljacii-strok-v)

Comment: Можете пример показать как это можно сделать через конкатенацию строк ?

Comment: А ни в одной книге для начинающих эта тема разве не описывается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы вывести результат в виде "123 * 45 = 5535" и при этом значения number_1 и number_2 вводятся пользователем, можно воспользоваться строковым форматированием. Вот как это можно реализовать в вашем коде:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите первое число: ");
        int number_1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Введите второе число: ");
        int number_2 = input.nextInt();

        int result = number_1 * number_2;

        System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d", number_1, number_2, result);
    }
}
```

В этом примере мы добавили переменную `result`, которая хранит результат умножения `number_1` на `number_2`. Затем мы используем метод `printf` класса `System.out` для форматированного вывода. Параметры `%d` указывают на то, что на их место должны подставляться целочисленные значения.

Comment: А как можно сделать с процентом? т.е: int result_5 = number_1 % number_2; System.out.printf("%d % %d = %d\n", number_1, number_2, result_4); как в таком случае добавить знак деление по модулю ? как я добавил не работает

Comment: @Aibek для вывода `%` при помощи форматированной строки нужно удвоить знак процента: `System.out.printf("%d %% %d = %d%n", number_1, number_2, number_1 % number_2);`