# return 1, return -1

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что значит `return 1` и `return -1` в конце методов, или в условии методов

Вопрос в следующем. Допустим, есть условие, в случае со строками

```
if (o1.length > o2.length) { return 1;} 
else if (o1.length < o2.length) { return -1;}
```

Это типа сортировка по возрастанию длины.
В данном примере что подразумевают эти команды `return`?

Comment: Нет такого "retern". Есть "return" - метод заканчивает свою работу и возвращает заданное значение.

Comment: да, опечатался, но вопрос в другом. допустим есть условие в случае со строками if(o1.length > o2.length) { retrn 1} else if (o1.length < o2.length) { return -1}.это типа сортировка по возрастанию длины. в данном примере что подразумевают эти команды return?

Comment: вам же ответили, возвращается либо `1`, либо `-1`, в зависимости от того, какое из условий сработает

Comment: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.17.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если попытаться догадаться, опираясь на информацию, что вы предоставили (вы сказали идет какая-то сортировка), cкорее всего речь идет об интерфейсе [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) или [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

При сортировке, чтобы понять, в каком порядке расположить элементы, сортирующая функция должна знать, как сравнивать ваши элементы.

Этот код скорее всего поясняет, как оценивать ваши элементы при сортировке:

```
-1 - значит при сортировке по возрастанию o1 должен стоять раньше o2.
1 - значит при сортировке по возрастанию o1 должен стоять после o2.
0 - o1 и o2 равны, порядок относительно друг друга не изменяется.
```

Comment: ахах, да, вы правильно меня поняли, скорее всего эти команды прописаны в реализации, спасибо за доходчивый ответ

Comment: @Абдулла пожалуйста) если больше нет вопросов, нажмите галочку рядом с ответом.

Comment: @NowhereMan понял, спасибо, ща исправлю

Answer (score 2):

Оператор **return** используется в функциях для возвращения данных после выполнения работы самой функции.

На вашем примере

```
if(o1.length > o2.length) // если длина o1 (o1.length) больше, чем длина o2(o2.length) 
{ return 1 } // вернется 1 из функции
else if (o1.length < o2.length) // если длина o1 (o1.length) меньше, чем длина o2 (o.length)
{ return -1} // вернется -1 из функции
```

В данной функции ещё есть **необработанный случай**, при котором `o1.length == o2.length`